# Control system variables within a MySQL Transaction's scope

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

MySQL allows users to manipulate [dynamic system variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/dynamic-system-variables.html) within both `GLOBAL` and `SESSION` level scopes at runtime. I have noticed that if you set a `SESSION` scoped system variable within a transaction, commits and rollbacks leave that `SESSION` scoped variable in its altered state. **Is there a way to limit the scope of the alteration of a system variable to a single transaction, or at the very least, reset it to its original pre-transaction value on rollback?**

As an example of where this is relevant, here is what I am doing as a workaround [due to the lack of NOWAIT support in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22286/similar-function-nowait-in-mysql):

```sql
SET @cachedTimeout = @@SESSION.INNODB_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT;
SET @@SESSION.INNODB_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT = 1;

SELECT * FROM sometable FOR UPDATE;

SET @@SESSION.INNODB_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT = COALESCE(@cachedTimeout, @@SESSION.INNODB_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT);
```

In the above example, if the `SELECT` query fails for whatever reason, I would like to rollback to the previous timeout value.